# How do I automate an MSI install on a Server 2003 box?

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting, automated-install

I have about 20 applications that need to be run in a specific order. I want to script them so that I can do this remotely.

Each one of the applications has a Setup.exe and an MSI.

I was hoping just to have a simple script that called the MSIs with an answer file, but it has been years since I have done it. However, I do not remember how to create an answer file.

Is this a good way to do it? Or would there be a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

There may be better ways to do this, but here are some things I would try:

- If the exe's are InstallShield, you can try to create an iss answer file for them. Run the exe with this command line:

> setup.exe -r -f1c:\product.iss

After running that and doing an install, you should have an install file that you can reference using this:

```
C:\setup.exe -s -f1C:\product.iss
```

- You could instead use the MSI's, and create a transform with a program called Orca. I don't know too much about that program to provide specific help, but once you have a transform, then you just need to run:

> msiexec /I setup.msi /q TRANSFORMS=transform.mst